# Best way to mount 3-4 monitor like this?

Tags: multiple-monitors, mount, vesa

I just purchased 2 HP 2009m widescreen monitors, they are not the biggest thing on the block, they are like 19-20" and are only around $150-$200 so I think they are perfect.  I bought 2 of them just to make sure I like them, with the full intention of purchasing more to make either a triple or quad display.

I now I am stuck trying to decide, if I purchase 1 more to have a triple display I would then like to just wrap the third monitor to either the right or left side, I could do this without a mount most likely pretty easy.  If I decide to go with 2 more monitors to make a quad display then I would like to add the 2 new monitor directly above the 2 that I have now.  So it would make a grid of 2 wide and 2 high.

The two that I currently have are tilted inwards to make more of a "V" shape instead of them being side by side and "STRAIGHT".

Now if I decide to make the grid of 4 then I will need to buy or build a stand to hold them all tightly together (no whitespace or gap between the grid of monitors) but I would like to still have both rows invert to make the slight "V".

Do you know of any existing stands I could purchase that would hold all 4 monitors without making them be STARIGHT without the "V" shape?

Any tips appreciated please, also they do have holes in the back for VESA.

Comment: Can't see the photos.

Answer (score 1):

Those monitors really have too wide of a bezel to work great in that configuration. Better off going with something like the [HP L2045w](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824176073) or even step up to a profesional monitor like the [LP2065](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824176053)

I know that doesn't really answer your question but I don't think you will be happy with those monitors.

Comment: I am just curious, what would make the monitors you mentioned better?  Just the bevel or is there other things I should be looking at as well?  Thanks for the input

Comment: With that many monitors you might want to run some of them in portrait mode. Low end monitors don't work in portrait mode. Even if you mounted it on a stand they normally don't have a wide enough viewing angle to make it work. I have four monitors 3 20" in portrait mode and 1 15" in landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Your pictures aren't showing up for me, though previous replier could see them I guess.

A few suggestions to consider:

- There are manufacturers who sell modular pole and rail based style systems.  You can then place the monitors anywhere along the vertical or horizontal supports.  Though it sounds like you want to might want to preserve your existing mounts and add to it.  These systems can typically either clamped to the back of a table, or mounted to walls.
- You could consider wall mounting some of the monitors.  You'd have more options for where to put the mounts.  For example, you could have a dual display on your desk, and then wall mounts for the upper monitors, with arms that extend them out far enough to be in a plane with the other two, so all four are still act as one group.  This might wind up being cheaper, though not as cool.  The advantage for the higher wall mounts is that you're only paying for the "arm/mount" portion, with the wall providing the height, vs. paying for a quad display setup, where you're paying for the extra metal, etc.
- Another suggestion, even cheaper, would be use shelves.  I know that's very "low tech", but lots of modular shelves are adjustable.  And you can buy really inexpensive rails, brackets and shelves at the local hardware store, and put them anywhere you want.  Or get a rolling adjustable shelving unit, which look pretty cool.  Maybe still keep a table or desk for your keyboard, mouse and CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your photos, but I thought I'd recommend an affordable stand:

[http://www.amazon.com/Quad-Monitor-stand-Fully-adjustable/dp/B001HHNRFK/ref=sr_1_5?s=office-products&ie=UTF8&qid=1306627043&sr=1-5](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001HHNRFK)[image]

I have purchased a few of the [dual-monitor version](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002R9HQLI) (same thing, just with a shorter pole and one less double bracket) and have been extremely happy with it.  There is also a [triple-monitor version](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0023ED22Y).

You can adjust it however you want, and angle each monitor independently.  The only thing fixed is the vertical position between two monitors side by side.  Everything else is adjustable in any manner.